# Thevenin Equivalent of a common emitter amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier, thevenin

Consider a CE (Common Emitter) Amplifier without the emitter capacity. After having determined the operating point we pass on to the small-signal analysis. It doesn't matter what model we use (personally, I use either the h-model or the pi-model).

Now, I would like to represent the circuit thus obtained as a two-port quadrupole as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ5tTg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To this purpose may use Thevenin Theorem to find the equivalent of our circuit under the input port and then under the output port. However when I applied the theorem I couldn't obtain the desired results if compared with those I could find on the internet and with those handed by my teacher. He says that my problem is that I open the current source (I am now referring to the h-model,) when I apply the theorem. However when I studied it, this was part of the statement.

Could someone enlighten me on how to apply Thevenin Theorem correctly in this case?

Comment: You need also a voltage generator in series with Rin

Comment: @Antonio51 My teacher did not use that because he said that it must be connected from the outside.